# Android : Thread does not start

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, ar.drone

I try to build an application to control a drone PARROT.
For this i create a socket between the drone and the device and i put this in a thread.
At first the thread correctly ran  and the drone took off but now (i didn't touch at my code) , the drone don't want take off. I notice the thread doesn't run now (whereas it ran correctly before)
Here is my code with the Thread:

```
String commande="";
byte[] cmdToByte;
InetAddress IpDrone;
DatagramSocket clientSocket;
boolean etat;
DatagramPacket sendPacketWithCmd;
private byte[] ip = {(byte)192, (byte)168, (byte)1, (byte)1 };
boolean isRunning = true;
private final static long TIME_SLEEP= 20;

public void run() {
        try {
    IpDrone = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {

    etat = true;
    }

    try {
    clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    } catch (SocketException e) {

    etat = true;
    }

    while(isRunning){

    runControl();
    etat = true;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(TIME_SLEEP);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

    }
public void runControl(){

commande = "AT*REF=1,290717696<LF>AT*REF=2,290717952<LF>AT*REF=3,290717696<LF>";

cmdToByte = commande.getBytes();


try {

sendPacketWithCmd = new DatagramPacket(cmdToByte,cmdToByte.length,IpDrone,5556);                    
clientSocket.send(sendPacketWithCmd);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    etat = true;
            }
etat = true;
isRunning=false;
clientSocket.disconnect();
clientSocket.close();
            }
```

I know there are AsyncTask but i really want to do this with my own thread.
So i would like to know what is my problem, why my thread does not start (in the main activity, i run my thread with start()).
Thanking you in advance !

Comment: could u please align your code?

Answer (score 2):

try to use thread like that

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

       @Override
        public void run() {
            // put ur code here

        }
      }).start();
```

Comment: Had a similar issue recently, and I found the @Override had gone missing accidently. Added it back and it is working fine now.